# Kill all processes of an application that use less than X of RAM in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to kill all the processes of an application that use less than X of RAM.

On **Windows**:

`taskkill /F /FI "memusage lt 10000" /IM app.exe`

This command kills all app.exe processes that use less than 10000 KB of RAM.

What is the equivalent in **Linux**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

list all pids that use RAM < 2%

```
min=2
ps ww -eo pid,pcpu,pmem,rss,cmd --sort rss | awk -vmin=$min '$3<min'
```

kill them:

```
kill $(ps ww -eo pid,pcpu,pmem,rss | awk '$3<min{print $1}')
```

Or if you want to check [***R**esident **S**et **S**ize*](https://linuxconfig.org/ps-output-difference-between-vsz-vs-rss-memory-usage) < 8GiB:

```
min=$((8*1024))
ps ww -eo pid,pcpu,pmem,rss,cmd --sort rss | awk -v min=$min '$4<min'
```

Kill them:

```
kill $(ps ww -eo pid,pcpu,pmem,rss | awk -v min=$min '$4<min{print $1}')
```